# Permissions Error #200 on creating new blank Custom Audience through FB Ads API

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-ads-api

I am getting the following error when trying to create a new blank Custom Audience through the Facebook Ads API. I have a whitelisted APP_ID. The ads_management extended permission is enough? The user must be an Administrator of the ads account to be able to do it?

```
{
"error"=>{
    "message"=>"(#200) Permissions error",
    "type"=>"OAuthException",
    "code"=>200
}
}
```

Comment: If you get this error through the API, access your account using Power Editor and create a new Custom Audience. Accept the Custom Audience Terms and try again.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the power editor and start to create a new custom audience and accept the TOS before you are able to do it through the API the first time.